# xPages and html template - different size of elements

Tags: html, css, xpages

I use a html template in an xPages application. All elements seem a little bit larger like in plain html page. If I compare values in Chrome debugger all values seem the same.

[image: plain html template]

[image: xpages page]

Answer (score 1):

Do you use a theme? If so, I recommend extending your theme from "" (nothing) instead of using "webstandard" or similar as this loads some Dojo related CSS stuff which may cause these differences.
If not, then consider to use one and set it up like described above.

Comment: I do not extend the theme, it is created from blank. I do not have any Dojo related CSS stuff. If I look at the css of elements they seem the same. I tried also with different doc types, but it goes to worse representation of css. From source point it seems pretty clear css. I have added xsp-core.css but also without it, it is scaled a little bit.